# how to Prioritize queued events?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am working in laravel 5.0

I am using database as queue driver.
I have created 2 events A and B. I want event B to always execute first.
Even if Event B is inserted in Jobs table after Event A it should execute first.

Both of my events consists of

```
implements ShouldBeQueued
```

and

```
 use InteractsWithQueue;
```

My Event handler is like this..

```
 <?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\Events\A;

use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class A implements ShouldBeQueued { 
use InteractsWithQueue; 

/**
 * Create the event handler.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  A  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(A $event)
{
    $alldeviceID = $event->alldeviceID;
    $gcmMessage  = $event->gcmMessage;


    send_notification($alldeviceID, $gcmMessage);

 }
}
```

So both events are going into jobs table and i have supervisor(process manager) to handle them..

It is working fine so far, Just that i want to give high priority to Event B over Event A.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for laravel > 5.0.**
According to the manual https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues#queue-priorities you should define different queues for this purpose e.g names `high` and `low`. Message with higher priority should go to `high` queue like `dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('high'));`. What is more you should start your workers with following command

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=high,low --daemon
```

where `--queue=high,low` defines the priority in which messages will be processed.

**Solution for laravel 5.0**

```
\Queue::pushOn('high', new Job);
```

You should start your workers with following command

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=high,low --daemon
```

Comment: I am familiar with this but my environment is laravel 5.0.. and i don't know how would i give priority to event?

Comment: I have updated question, my event is like this.. where should i put \Queue::pushOn('high', new Job);

Comment: @Jaimin Where do you push jobs to queue? I don't see this code.

Comment: I just need to change this code...updated the code...class A implements ShouldBeQueued {

use InteractsWithQueue;

Comment: This is a definition for your job. Somewhere in the code you should dispatch it to the queue. I will suggest you to read manual https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues again. @Jaimin